# Mongoose Methods

Tags: mongoose, bcrypt, mongoose-schema

I'm using mongoose in my project where am hashing password before saving with UserSchema.pre() function. It works fine and encrypted the password. But when am using UserSchema.methods.comparePassword, It shows me an error on methods as. methods is declared but never used its value. Below is the code I'm using

```
'use strict';
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

    const UserSchema = new Schema({
        company_id: String,
        branch_id: String,
        name: String,
        email : String,
        password: String,
    });

    UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
        var user = this;
        if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();
        if(user.password) {
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
                if(err) return next(err);
                bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
                    if(err) return next();
                    user.password = hash;
                    next(err)
                })
            })
        }
    });

    UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword)  {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(candidatePassword, this.password);
    };

    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get ride of the .methods `UserSchema.comparePassword` should be fine